# tkinter- subclass of button not placing on screen from inside another class

Tags: python, button, tkinter, subclass

I'm making a ide for brainf*ck in python using tkinter and I'm adding a recent projects section but when I'm placing the buttons they do not appear on the screen.

Here is the code for the `Scene`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as File
import tkinter as tk


class HoverButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.defaultBackground = "#5d5d5d"
        self['background'] = self.defaultBackground
        self['activebackground'] = "#6d6d6d"
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self['background'] = "#6d6d6d"

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self['background'] = self.defaultBackground


class ProjectPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, projects=[]):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.projects = projects
        self.buttons = []
        self.mstr = self.master.master
        self.title = "PesolIde: Projets"
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 500
        self.color = "#4d4d4d"
        self.projectFrame = tk.Frame(self.mstr,width=800,height=50,bg="#5d5d5d")
        self.newProject = HoverButton(self.mstr,text="New Project", height=1, bg="#6d6d6d")
        self.openProject = HoverButton(self.mstr,text="Open Project", height=1,bg="#6d6d6d", command=OpenAsk)
        self.projectdisplay = tk.Frame(self.mstr, width=700, height=300, bg="#5d5d5d", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
        for i in range(len(self.projects)):
            self.buttons.append(HoverButton(master, text=self.projects[i].split(':')[0], width=50, height=1))
            if len(self.buttons)>=40:
                break
        self.loaded = False
    def show(self):
        self.projectFrame.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.newProject.place(x=20, y=10)
        self.openProject.place(x=120, y=10)
        self.projectdisplay.place(x=50,y=100)
        self.y = 100
        print(len(self.buttons))
        for i in range(len(self.buttons)):
            print("placing " + str(self.buttons[i]))
            self.buttons[i].place(x=50,y=100+(20*i))
        self.master.set(title=self.title,width=self.width,height=self.height)
        self.master.master['bg'] = self.color
    def hide(self):
        self.newProject.place_forget()
        self.openProject.place_forget()
    def load(self):
        if not self.loaded:
            self.newProject.place_forget()
            self.openProject.place_forget()
            self.loaded = True
    def unload(self):
        self.newProject.destroy()
        self.openProject.destroy()


def OpenAsk():
    name = File.askopenfilename()
```

and here is the code for `main.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
import src.framework.modules.Window.Window as windows
import src.framework.src.Scenes.all as Scenes
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
window = windows.window(root, "", 800, 500)
window.place()
projects = open("projects.txt",'r').read().split("\n")

start = Scenes.ProjectPage.ProjectPage(window,projects)
start.show()

window.mainloop()
```

When I make a `HoverButton` outside the `ProjectPage` class in the `ProjectPage` file, it appears as expected but not when initialised from within the class of directly from the main file.

Here are some screenshots.

The output from running `main.py`:

[image: the output from main]

The output from running from outside the `ProjectPage` class with the code on the left:

[image: the output and code from outside the class]

Comment: Could you please combine the code into a single runnable [mcve] that illustrates the problem. It's hard to understand what you're asking. Give us a program and then tell us where you think the button should be. When I extract just the HoverButton class, it always appears exactly where I would expect it to appear.

Comment: the problem was fixed by Baraa it turns out in the loop that creates the buttons i passed master instead of self.master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert values for relx, rely, relwidth, relheight as attributes in "place" or you can as well insert height, width as attributes for place.
Check out the documentation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm

Comment: Would I insert 0's or give them functional values?

Comment: yes, you need to give them functional values: i.e. like the specific location for the button

Comment: This little tutorial might help you: https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/29714/place--

Comment: For example button.place(relx= 0.125, rely=0.2)

Comment: Yes, something like that as long as it satisfies the location where you want it to be. The values mean that the upper-left corner of the button will appear at 12.5% away from the left side and 20% away from the upper side. You can control that.

Comment: are you tlking about the code in the picture or where it says    self.buttons.append()

Comment: In the last comment I was talking about this: (relx= 0.125, rely=0.2)

Comment: ah no I meant in your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218599/discussion-between-reece-and-baraa).